# LUIS is not able to understand different entities [Edited]

Tags: botframework

So, I have a bot that uses LUIS. I have several utterances I have trained LUIS on, but the issue I am facing is that when I enter utterances that are not specific, like, ***Subpractice*** contact from **location** or ***skill*** contact from **location**, where words in bold refer to entities and both of these utterances are different, bot cannot comprehend if something I entered is a skill or a subpractice. Is there a way to train LUIS other than changing the utterance to get the desired output without the ambiguity?

Edit:
While the above issue remains these are the issues that we are facing:
[This is the query that works as both the values are in the Luis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGqT1.png)

[This does not capture the location as the location is not in the Luis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PDUC.png)

[This does not work at all as both the skill and location are not in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXYcu.png)

Comment: Please post the code you are using

Comment: The two utterances you listed are contextually the same. Is there any other words around them that would differentiate them? Or could you a list entity where subpractice is one item of list (with synonyms as values) and skill is another (with synonyms as values).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the recently launched Patterns feature to solve your issue.
Go to your Luis app and click on Patterns under 'Improve app performance'.

Select the intent, then enter the following template utterance:

```
{x} contact from {location}
```

where `{}` syntax marks the entity location within the template utterance as well as which entity it is.

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern#add-the-template-utterances) to know about Patterns

Answer (score 0):

> the issue I am facing is that when I enter utterances that are not specific, like, Subpractice contact from location or skill contact from location, where words in bold refer to entities and both of these utterances are different, bot cannot comprehend if something I entered is a skill or a subpractice.

It seems that you defined `Subpractice` and `skill` entities, but your LUIS app does not recognize entities as you expected. To solve it, you can try:

- add more utterances and manually [label the word(s) in the utterance to an entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/label-suggested-utterances#label-entities)
- if the data values of `Subpractice` and `skill` are a known/fixed set, you can define them as [list entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-quickstart-intent-and-list-entity).
- if the data values of `Subpractice` and `skill` are not fixed set, you can use [phrase list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-feature) to improve your LUIS app's performance.